# How can I simplify a multi switch case statement?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to simplify a switch statement so it doesn't take up so much room.
I feel like I just have too much repeated code. I don't know if there is a better statement to use or a way to clean up this code. I'm also very new to C++ so any tips would help.

This is what I made for drawing a die

```
void Dice::DrawDie()
{
    switch (LastRoll)
    {
    case 1: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|       |\n|   o   |\n|       |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 2: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|    o  |\n|       |\n|  o    |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 3: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|    o  |\n|   o   |\n|  o    |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 4: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 5: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|   o   |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 6: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|  o o  |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
    }
    switch (LastRoll2)
    {
    case 1: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|       |\n|   o   |\n|       |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 2: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|    o  |\n|       |\n|  o    |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 3: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|    o  |\n|   o   |\n|  o    |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 4: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 5: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|   o   |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 6: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|  o o  |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
    }
    switch (LastRoll3)
    {
    case 1: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|       |\n|   o   |\n|       |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 2: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|    o  |\n|       |\n|  o    |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 3: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|    o  |\n|   o   |\n|  o    |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 4: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 5: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|   o   |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 6: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|  o o  |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
    }
    switch (LastRoll4)
    {
    case 1: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|       |\n|   o   |\n|       |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 2: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|    o  |\n|       |\n|  o    |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 3: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|    o  |\n|   o   |\n|  o    |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 4: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 5: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|   o   |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 6: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|  o o  |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
    }
    switch (LastRoll5)
    {
    case 1: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|       |\n|   o   |\n|       |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 2: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|    o  |\n|       |\n|  o    |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 3: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|    o  |\n|   o   |\n|  o    |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 4: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 5: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|   o   |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 6: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|  o o  |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
    }
}
```

Then I use a separate area for rolling the dice one for each die. I make a new die for each one.

```
void Dice::Dice1()
{
    int RollNum;
    LastRoll = 0;
    TotalRolls++;

    //Gens Rand Num 1-6
     RollNum = (rand() % 6) + 1;
     LastRoll = RollNum;

}
```

Comment: Write a function to draw a die, and it takes the value as an argument. If you're repeating yourself, a function or loop gets the job done.

Comment: As far as I see all those switch blocks are identical. Simply extracting the switch into a function and calling that six times with the different LastRolls as a parameter would go a long way to avoid duplication.

Comment: I'd suggest making a function that takes an `int` as an argument and returns a `std::string` representing the roll, then calling that function each time you want to display the result of a roll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store just the die faces in a `std::map<int,std::array<const char*,5>>` and separate string literals for better readability:

```
const std::map<int,std::array<const char*,5>> die_faces = {
    { 1, { "+---+",
           "|   |",
           "| o |",
           "|   |",
           "+---+" } },
    { 2, { "+---+",
           "|o  |",
           "|   |",
           "|  o|",
           "+---+" } },
    { 3, { "+---+",
           "|o  |",
           "| o |",
           "|  o|",
           "+---+" } },
    { 4, { "+---+",
           "|o o|",
           "|   |",
           "|o o|",
           "+---+" } },
    { 5, { "+---+",
           "|o o|",
           "| o |",
           "|o o|",
           "+---+" } },
    { 6, { "+---+",
           "|o o|",
           "|o o|",
           "|o o|",
           "+---+" } }
    };
```

And access these like

```
void output_dies(int roll1, int roll2) {
    std::cout << "\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << die_faces.at(roll1)[i] << "\t" << die_faces.at(roll2)[i] << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

and

```
output_dies(LastRoll,LastRoll2);
```

No more switch needed at all.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62355cddfef32480)

Comment: Isn't a std::map a bit over the edge where the values are known to be 1..6?

Comment: @Surt I fixed everything now. I don't think it's much of overhead here; but readability rules. Maybe an even simpler data structure + some index calculation would do as well.

Comment: [Shameless rip-off](https://godbolt.org/z/M1rvxc) :-)

Comment: @Ted Well, you know under which license we're posting here,

Comment: Yeah, my rip-off is also PD ... darn :-)

Comment: @Ted For what are you using it, if I may ask?

Comment: What? My version of the dice-thingy? Nothing. I started doing it for fun when the question was posted and found it almost finished in an old chrome-tab right now. It does look like a rip-off so I didn't wanna post it as an answer though ...

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was just curios ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have a LOT of repeated code. A good rule to abide for clean code is [DRY--Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (after which my coworker will always say "What?" to make me repeat the description).

In this case, you can avoid all of the copy-paste by making a function, `display_die()` like:

```
std::string str_rev(std::string str) {
    std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
    return str;
}

void display_die(int val) {
    if(val < 1 || val > 6) { return; } // Bad value

    std::vector<std::string> first_face = {"   ", "  o", "  o", "o o", "o o", "o o"};
    std::vector<std::string> second_face = {" o ", "   ", " o ", "   ", " o ", "o o"};
    std::string lead = "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  ";
    std::string split = "  |\n|  ";
    std::string trail = "  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";

    std::cout << lead << first_face[val - 1] << split 
        << second_face[val - 1] << split
        << str_rev(first_face[val - 1]) << trail;
}
```

See it run here: https://ideone.com/lEJDzK

Comment: While I agree with DRY, I don't think that such constructs as shown in your answer are good, because it is hard to figure out if they are correct and why the contents of `firest_face` and `second_face` should create correct results when reading the code in code review. And your solution produces a different layout to the original code for  `3` and wrong results for `2` and `4`.

Comment: Ahh good call @t.niese, I didn't notice first and last faces were reversed, I've fixed that. I'm not sure how this is any more difficult to see the correctness of than the original though. On the contrary, the goal here was the clean final single `std::cout`.

Comment: `I'm not sure how this is any more difficult to see the correctness of than the original though.` shouldn't that be obvious because it is still not correct? For your code `display_die(2);` is an empty box, `display_die(4);` displays two dots instead of four.

Comment: Ha. I think you're attributing my own rush-job and lack of proofreading to a lack of readability, @t.niese It's what I get for rushing answers here. But if you don't think it's "clean," then perhaps you have different taste than I do.

Comment: Personally I'd define `third_face` and call `str_rev` when setting that up. That would improve readability. These variables could also be `static const`. But then again so could all the faces. Oh 'eck I'm starting to contradict myself as we're back to hardcoding everything. Just have an upvote!

Comment: Nitpick: `std::vector` is overkill for storing compile-time data. `std::array` or just an array will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function `void DrawDie(int RollNum)`, and call it with `DrawDie(LastRoll1)`, …

```
void DrawDie(int RollNum) {
    switch (RollNum)
    {
    case 1: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|       |\n|   o   |\n|       |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 2: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|    o  |\n|       |\n|  o    |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 3: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|    o  |\n|   o   |\n|  o    |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 4: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 5: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|   o   |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
        break;
    case 6: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|  o o  |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
    }
}
```

And `\n ------- \n|       |\n|` and `|\n|       |\n ------- \t` could be moved before and after the switch.

```
void DrawDie(int RollNum) {
    cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|";
    switch (RollNum)
    {
    case 1: cout << "       |\n|   o   |\n|       ";
        break;
    case 2: cout << "    o  |\n|       |\n|  o    ";
        break;
    case 3: cout << "    o  |\n|   o   |\n|  o    ";
        break;
    case 4: cout << "  o o  |\n|       |\n|  o o  ";
        break;
    case 5: cout << "  o o  |\n|   o   |\n|  o o  ";
        break;
    case 6: cout << "  o o  |\n|  o o  |\n|  o o  ";
    }
    cout << "|\n|       |\n ------- \t";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several blocks that are exactly the same apart from one variable `FOO`

```
switch (FOO)
{
case 1: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|       |\n|   o   |\n|       |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
    break;
case 2: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|    o  |\n|       |\n|  o    |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
    break;
case 3: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|    o  |\n|   o   |\n|  o    |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
    break;
case 4: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
    break;
case 5: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|   o   |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
    break;
case 6: cout << "\n ------- \n|       |\n|  o o  |\n|  o o  |\n|  o o  |\n|       |\n ------- \t";
}
```

Use a function:

```
void output(int i) {
    switch(i) {
        case 1: //...
        case 2: //...
    }
}
```

Then your code becomes:

```
void Dice::DrawDie() {
    output(LastRoll);
    output(LastRoll2);
    output(LastRoll3);
    output(LastRoll4);
    output(LastRoll5);     
}
```

Next you probably want to store the rolls in a container, then the method is simply:

```
void Dice::DrawDie() {
    for (auto& roll : last_rolls) output(roll);
}
```