# Output the repetitive ASCII diamonds

Tags: c++, output, ascii, ascii-art

My desired output looks about like this:

```
    **         **         **         **         **
   ****       ****       ****       ****       ****
  ******     ******     ******     ******     ******
 ********   ********   ********   ********   ********
********** ********** ********** ********** **********
********** ********** ********** ********** **********
 ********   ********   ********   ********   ********
  ******     ******     ******     ******     ******
   ****       ****       ****       ****       ****
    **         **         **         **         **
    **         **         **         **         **
   ****       ****       ****       ****       ****
  ******     ******     ******     ******     ******
 ********   ********   ********   ********   ********
********** ********** ********** ********** **********
********** ********** ********** ********** **********
 ********   ********   ********   ********   ********
  ******     ******     ******     ******     ******
   ****       ****       ****       ****       ****
    **         **         **         **         **
    **         **         **         **         **
   ****       ****       ****       ****       ****
  ******     ******     ******     ******     ******
 ********   ********   ********   ********   ********
********** ********** ********** ********** **********
********** ********** ********** ********** **********
 ********   ********   ********   ********   ********
  ******     ******     ******     ******     ******
   ****       ****       ****       ****       ****
    **         **         **         **         **
```

I've been able to figure out how to get the first diamond shape with the following:

```
//inside of a void function called printDots()
char dot = '*';
char blank = ' ';

for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    for (int k = 6; k > i; k--) { // right-shifts the first triangle
        std::cout << blank;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { // first triangle
        std::cout << dot;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { // second triangle (left-aligned)
        std::cout << dot;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) { // right-shifts the third triangle
        std::cout << blank;
    }
    for (int j = 6; j > i; j--) { // third triangle
        std::cout << dot;
    }
    for (int j = 6; j > i; j--) { // fourth triangle (left-aligned)
        std::cout << dot;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to repeat this shape in the desired pattern, though. I've tried adding more `for` loops to do the same thing that I'm already doing to make all four parts of the diamond, but it seems to just be shifting the asterisks down vertically and disrupting the pattern, all without achieving any of the horizontal output. I could just manually output the pattern with a large `std::cout` statement, but I'm trying to figure out how to generate the shape rather than just copying and pasting it. Any advice?

Comment: C++ doesn't have an easy, built-in way to draw one shape and then go back up a few lines to start drawing in the next shape. This pretty much forces you to stop thinking about the problem as repeating shapes and instead as a pattern.

Comment: @user4581301 I think I'm confused a bit by your answer. For clarification, what is the difference between "repeating shapes" and a "pattern"? Could you demonstrate the difference?

Comment: On the other hand, if each shape is it's own instance of  an object, complete with a function that allows the object to be drawn one one at a time, you can have a nested loop that calls `DrawLine` for a row of objects... And Martin York just took this to the logical conclusion.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm sorry, but which header is the die faces example under? It looks like that link is just a guide to formatting text on StackOverflow, but maybe I'm not reading where I need to be reading.

Comment: @NicholasJarecki Sorry so much, that link was still at my clipboard. Here's the one I meant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64342037/how-can-i-simplify-a-multi-switch-case-statement/64342211#64342211 The die faces are stored ther in a `std::array<const char*,5>`. You'll need a different container for your shape, something like a `std::vector<std::string>`, where you populate each row with the `' '` and `'*'` characters appropriately once. If you have that you can use the technique, to print that shape repeatedly in rows and colums, using such code as shown in the loop.

Comment: @NicholasJarecki You can play at bit with the code I posted in the linked demo.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking to write all code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would redesign your app so you have a function that prints one line of the diamond:

So the initial program looks like this:

```
void printDiamondLine(int line)
{
    // You write this part
}

int main()
{
     for(int loop = 0; loop < sizeOfDiamong; ++loop)
     {
         printDiamondLine(loop);
         std::cout << "\n";
     }
}
```

This should print out:

```
    **    Notice that each line is space filled on both sides.
   ****   
  ******  
 ******** 
**********
**********
 ******** 
  ******  
   ****   
    **
```

Now you can alter the code to print multiple diamnons:

```
int main()
{
     // Looping over the whole things
     // to get multiple lines of diamonds.
     for(int vertical = 0; vertical < verticalDiamonds; ++vertical)
     {
         for(int loop = 0; loop < sizeOfDiamong; ++loop)
         {
             // Printing each line of the diamond
             // multiple times across.
             for(int horz = 0; horz < horzDiamonds; ++horz)
             {
                 printDiamondLine(loop);
                 std::cout << " ";
             }
             std::cout << "\n";
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to think about it more as 1 line at a time. Your first big foo-loop produces the top half of each diamond, and the second big for-loop produces the bottom half, yes?

I'm just going to deal with half of that, because it becomes the same solution fro the top and bottom:

```
// This produces 5 lines of output.
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    // This puts out leading spaces as required for this line
    for (int k = 6; k > i; k--) { // right-shifts the first triangle
        std::cout << blank;
    }

    // This puts out the diamond itself -- just this line
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { // first triangle
        std::cout << dot;
    }

    // And this puts out the second half of the diamond -- just this line
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { // second triangle (left-aligned)
        std::cout << dot;
    }

    // Note: THIS IS WHERE WE'LL INSERT MORE CODE

    // And this is why you're only getting 1
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

I commented the code. So far, you're actually doing okay. But now, let's keep all that code, but I'm going to add a little bit before the final cout.

```
    for (int k = 6; k > i; k--) {
        std::cout << blank;
    }
```

What this does is space-fill the line so that (so far) each line is the same length.

And then all you have to do is wrap most of that code inside another for-loop. You end up with something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    for (int whichDiamond = 0; whichDiamond < 3; ++whichDiamond) {
        for (int k = 6; k > i; k--) { // right-shifts the first triangle
            std::cout << blank;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { // first triangle
            std::cout << dot;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { // second triangle (left-aligned)
            std::cout << dot;
        }
        for (int k = 6; k > i; k--) { // right-shifts the first triangle
            std::cout << blank;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

You can do the same sort of thing with the second of your big loops.

Now, there might be more clever ways of doing this, but this works from your existing code.